# Flyway : relation "flyway_schema_history" already exists

Tags: postgresql, flyway

Hi I am running Flyway with Docker and calling through CodeBuild.
But again and again I am getting the error even after dropped the table.

### ERROR: Migration of schema "public" to version "1 - fsp cdk 250821" failed! Changes successfully rolled back.
ERROR: Migration V1__PSK_cdk_250821.sql failed

### SQL State  : 42P07
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: relation "flyway_schema_history" already exists
Location   : sql/V1__PSK_cdk_250821.sql (/flyway/sql/V1__PSK_cdk_250821.sql)
Line       : 3811
Statement  : --
-- TOC entry 281 (class 1259 OID 36880)
-- Name: flyway_schema_history; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: ***

CREATE TABLE public.flyway_schema_history (
installed_rank integer NOT NULL,
version character varying(50),
description character varying(200) NOT NULL,
type character varying(20) NOT NULL,
script character varying(1000) NOT NULL,
checksum integer,
installed_by character varying(100) NOT NULL,
installed_on timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
execution_time integer NOT NULL,
success boolean NOT NULL
)

Caused by: Migration V1__PSK_cdk_250821.sql failed

Comment: are you creating the flyway table yourself ? if so don't either use baseline command or baselineOnMigrate option

Answer (score 1):

Is there any possibility of giving a minimal repro?
However, without that, it looks like you might be creating the Flyway Schema History table within your migration, which will conflict with Flyways own management of this table.